# java Netty Retrieve Data from Bytebuf

Tags: java, netty, bytebuffer

I am using java Netty 4 to read a external tcp socket to get some information and it returns the results as Bytebuf and pretty print looks as the attached screen shot

[image]

I went through the Bytebuf api and found there lots of methods to parse and read the Bytebuf content. I need to read the String data in column 3 to a java String. 
So i tried below

```
int startWritableIndex = (capacity-numberOFWritableBytes);
    for(int i = startWritableIndex; startWritableIndex < capacity; i++){
        System.out.println(buf.getByte(i));
    }
```

and it ended up with an outofbound exception and looks like it is not the solutions

What is the best possible way of doing this?

Thanks,
Keth

Comment: It looks like you are reading from the writable portion of the buffer. I suggest only reading, or writing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ByteBuf.toString(int, int, Charset)`